# Error while running ice on ubuntu ( java)

Tags: java, ubuntu, ice

I am having trouble while trying to run the example for printer.
when i try to run the class for the server it prints

```
Error: A JNI error has occurred, please check your installation and try again
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Ice/LocalException
    at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethods0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredMethods(Class.java:2701)
    at java.lang.Class.privateGetMethodRecursive(Class.java:3048)
    at java.lang.Class.getMethod0(Class.java:3018)
    at java.lang.Class.getMethod(Class.java:1784)
    at sun.launcher.LauncherHelper.validateMainClass(LauncherHelper.java:544)
    at sun.launcher.LauncherHelper.checkAndLoadMain(LauncherHelper.java:526)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Ice.LocalException
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:331)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
    ... 7 more
```

For what i have been searching it is caused by the classpath export?
i did export `CLASSPATH=$CLASSPATH:./classes:$ICE_HOME/share/java/ice.jar`

ICE_HOME is /usr.

Does anyone know how to fix? thanks

Comment: Possible duplicate..http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28922512/how-to-resolve-this-jni-error-when-trying-to-run-lwjgl-hello-world

Comment: the problem was a bit different, i was doing the right thing, it just was getting deleted but idk why

Answer (score 0):

After typing the question continued looking for it. As it seems exports are wierd, when i do ctrl + shift + T for a new terminal it deletes them. Only after looking at the exports page i realized they were getting deleted.